# what does uv_loop_t.time represent?

Tags: c++, libuv

In libuv's uv_loop_t, there is a private uint64 field called "time".

What does it represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libuv` caches the current time at the start of the event loop tick in order to reduce the number of time-related system calls ([see also](http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/loop.html#c.uv_update_time)).

So `time` certainly is the current time cached when your event loop is started. You can retrieve this value though [`uv_now`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/loop.html#c.uv_now) and update it using [`uv_update_time`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/loop.html#c.uv_update_time).